# How setup .UseEndpoints for prometheus in .NET 7 with minimal API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, prometheus, .net-7.0, prometheus-net

Before in .Net 6:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.AddMetrics();  ( inside => app.UseMiddleware<PrometheusMetricsMiddleware>();)
app.UseEndpoints(endpoint => endpoint.MapMetrics());
app.UseHttpMetrics();
```

In .NET 7 we have a problem with code:
app.UseEndpoints(endpoint => endpoint.MapMetrics());
ERROR - [ASP0014: Suggest using top level route registrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/diagnostics/asp0014?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1)

How can I fix it? ( without #pragma warning disable ASP0014 )

Answer (score 1):

Try just calling `MapMetrics` on the `app`:

```cs
app.MapMetrics();
```

Comment: mapMaterics() method not founded in app

Answer (score 0):

After `app.MapControllers()` add those two lines and it should work:

```
app.MapControllers();

app.UseHttpMetrics();
app.MapMetrics();
```